Transitivity of rational orthogonal matrices
It is well-known that the orthogonal group $O(n)$ acts transitively on the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^n$. What happens if we instead restrict ourselves to orthogonal matrices with rational coefficients? Do these act transitively on the rational points of the unit sphere?
This is easily shown for $n \le 2$. I would expect the theorem to be false for $n \ge 3$, but I haven't been able to find a counterexample or otherwise prove the claim.

It is proved in this REU paper by Calvin Lin Zhiwei that more is true: any set of orthonormal vectors $v_1, \dots, v_k$ with rational entries can be extended to an orthonormal basis with rational entries, ie $O(n, \mathbb{Q})$ acts transitively on the rational points of each Stiefel manifold $V_k(\mathbb{Q}^n)$, or in fact with $\mathbb{Q}$ replaced by any field of characteristic $0$.
The key observation is in fact the case $k = 1$ of the question. Given $v_1 = (a_1, \dots, a_n)$ of norm $1$, assuming $v_1 \ne -e_1$ without loss of generality, the following orthogonal map takes $v_1$ to $e_1$ and has rational coordinates:
$$v \mapsto 2 \frac{v \cdot (e_1 + v_1)}{(e_1 + v_1) \cdot (e_1 + v_1)} (e_1 + v_1) - v.$$
This is of course the orthogonal reflection fixing the line spanned by $e_1 + v_1$.

I expect that the conclusion was known earlier but this is the first source I found.

Wow, I feel dumb for forgetting about reflections. Thanks!
